# When to use homeAsUpIndicator in a toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-resources, android-theme

I see that in a `Toolbar` e.g.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator">
```

Either I add `app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"` or if that is missing i.e.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
```

the back arrow is displayed. I was wondering, is there a reason to add `?attr/homeAsUpIndicator` anyway?

Answer (score 0):

`?attr/homeAsUpIndicator`

Specifies a drawable to use for the 'home as up' indicator which is used to navigate back to former page or activity

It can also be added programmatically

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```

Visit https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#homeAsUpIndicator to
know about it...

I hope this helps...

Comment: My question is that either I have it defined in the `navigationIcon` either I don't an arrow for back still is shown. So what is the difference? I mean if by default it shows do I need to set `app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"`?

Comment: Oh i get your point now....by default you don't need to set `app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"` in your toolbar element